# ZF_DB: how to make simple select for two or more tables without join?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, nodes, nested-sets

Example:

```
SELECT `cat`.`id_catalog`, COUNT(parent.id_catalog) - 1) AS `level` FROM `tbl_catalog` AS `cat`, `tbl_catalog` AS `parent` WHERE (cat.`left` BETWEEN parent.`left` AND parent.`right`) GROUP BY `cat`.`id_catalog` ORDER BY `cat`.`left` ASC
```

It doesn't seem to work if it use ZF. ZF create this query with join only. How to create the select without join in ZF_DB.

By the way may be I do smth wrong in this query. It is simple nested set DB with parent, left and right fields. Perhaps there are another way to use join to get deep for some node. Anyway it would be interesting to get answer for both way:)

Thanks in advance to all who looks it through:)

Comment: Its solved and its enougth simple.
I solved it by using join, just added 1=1 to section "ON"
This is that I have as a result:

    SELECT `cat`.`id_catalog`, COUNT(parent.id_catalog) - 1) AS `level` FROM `tbl_catalog` AS `cat` INNER JOIN `tbl_catalog` AS `parent` ON 1=1 WHERE (cat.`left` BETWEEN parent.`left` AND parent.`right`) GROUP BY `cat`.`id_catalog` ORDER BY `cat`.`left` ASC

Comment: While that will work, an (arguably) better solution would be to put what you have in the WHERE clause in the JOIN instead, just to illustrate the distinction between your table JOIN and what results you are filtering by.